# Make FrameLayout match root parent

Tags: java, android, xml

In my "MainActivity.java" I have a FrameLayout so I can display every fragment that can be chosen in the menu.

I also have, after the FrameLayout, a bottom navigation bar which is identical to all of the menus. In one of those menus "Camera" I open my camera using a library and I hide my bottom navigation bar so the user can see the camera in a "immersive mode".

My problem is, how can I set my fragment to, in the moment that "camera" is clicked, be matched with the "MainActivity" and not with the FragmentLayout?

In other words, is there a way to make FrameLayout have height matched to "MainActivity" instead of a custom one?
I don't know if I was clear so here you have some photos:

**This is my frameLayout and my Bottom Navigation Bar in all fragments**

[image]

**I want to make, in the "Camera" fragment, the FrameLayout to be like this:**
[image]

Comment: you could start the camera in a new activity instead of embedding it in a fragment

Comment: I've thought of that but that there's a big difference in timing. Activities take a life to open. Fragments are instantaneous

Comment: You can load the camera fragment inside another container in `MainActivity` which is full height and width and have a background, and you can remove the fragment when you are done

Answer (score 0):

try this when you call the fragment that launches the camera:

```
BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
                navigation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

And put this in the activity where your camera is launched:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContex(), MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
    BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: Hm, but when the user goes back to another menu item, how can I make the menu appear again?

Comment: Thanks. What I wonder is, after the View.Gone can it go Visible again? I thought that could only become visible again if it was "INVISIBLE"

Comment: my first code you add it in the MainActivity when you call the fragment that launches the camera and my second code you add it in the fragment that launches the camera, so when you leave the camera for the main, there will be again the BottomBarNavigation.

Answer (score 0):

In the MainActivity do this
1-When you replacing fragment always save the fragment.

```
  private Fragment mCurrentFragment;

 public void addFragment(MyBaseFragment f, boolean clearBackStack, 

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, f);
        if (addToBackstack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        transaction.commit();

        mCurrentFragment = f;
        mFragments.push(f);

        onFragmentBackStackChanged();
    }
```

2-Then on the onFragmentBackStackChanged check the current fragment

```
@Override
    public void onFragmentBackStackChanged() {
        super.onFragmentBackStackChanged();
if(mCurrentFragment instanof CameraFragment){
bottomView.setvisibility(View.Gone)
}else{
bottomView.setvisibility(View.Visible)
}
}
```

Actually this will always track the current fragment so it will show and hide the view according to your current fragment.